Why does adjusting the current not do anything for my colpitts oscillator?
I discovered that the swing of the oscillator I have been working on is effected by the Q factor of the inductor I am using. The inductor is CTTF0402F-2N2C. The relation between the Q factor and the startup condition is this (from razavi's fundamental of electronics book):


Since Q is 13 (from the datasheet) and given by the relation:

We can see that the formula for Rp above is the same as Rp = QwL. And from this, we can determine if gmRp is large enough to satisfy the startup condition - it has to be equal to or larger than 4 as given in the razavi book if the output is taken at the collector. gm is the collector current divided by the thermal voltage 26mV. Rp would 77.3 ohms. This means gm77.3 must be greater than 4, which means gm must be greater or equal to 5.2 mS (millisiemens). This means the collector current must be greater than: Vt5.2mS = 1.35mA. I met this condition but the oscillator still doesn't oscillate unless the bias resistors are small. Why is this?
here is the circuit:


Please post the schematic of your oscillator in this question, so that readers do not need to visit your previous questions to understand this one.

This one uses a common base amplifier. The base should be coupled to the ground via a capacitor. Insert one, say 1 nF in parallel with R1 and another in parallel with R2 if you really build the circuit. This stops the harmful feedback effect of the CB-capacitance inside the transistor. In a practical circuit you need both capacitors to make long enough DC supply wires possible. As you have noticed, it can oscillate also without the capacitors if R1 and R2 have low enough resistances.

but why does it not oscillate if the bias resistors R1 and R2 are larger than a few hundred ohms? I still don't understand.

Collector to base capacitance is substantial and it causes negative feedback which reduces the available gain. That's why the common base amplifier is often better in rf applications. Of course, the capacitive CB feedback could be neutralized with properly designed reactive circuits, but that's tricky. It's done in common emitter RF amplifiers. Low resistance R1 and R2 suppress the leaked signal by loading it dead. The inserted capacitors do the same, but without excessive DC current.

when you say "suppress the leaked signal", you mean it sort of provides a path to ac ground?

Also shouldn't one capacitor be enough? it would be in parallel to both the resistors when viewed by the ac signal.

One is enough if your DC power supply is ideal (=simulated). Practical power supply has inductive wires, so there must be a decoupling capacitor between plus and minus as close your circuit as possible. By inserting one capacitor in parallel with  R1 and another in parallel with R2 you can have the properly decoupled base and power supply. But as well you can have one capacitor in parallel with either R1 or R2 and the other should in that case be between DC plus and minus. Having the capacitors in parallel with R1 and R2 can simplify the practical wiring in some cases.

You forgot to decouple the base of the transistor to ground with a capacitor (e.g. 1nF or similar). L1/C1/C2 are also not very practical values for an UHF oscillator. Try something more like 18nH/15pF/18pF to get close to 400MHz:

